# .focus() not working while inside .on('click', function(event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

I'm using the following function to scroll the page to a specific element when a link is clicked, which works just fine:

```
$('a.scroll-link').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href')
    if (target.length) {               
        event.preventDefault();               
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 800);

    }
});
```

I'm trying to add a focus() event to focus on an entire form element. It's not working and I can't figure out why. I have tried several variations of the following code:

```
$('a.scroll-link').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href')
    if (target.length) {               
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#mainForm').focus();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 800);

    }
});
```

Variation #2:

```
$('a.scroll-link').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#mainForm').focus();
    var target = $(this).attr('href')
    if (target.length) {               
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 800);

    }
});
```

Variation #3 with timeout:

```
$('a.scroll-link').on('click', function(event) {
    var target = $(this).attr('href')
    if (target.length) {               
        event.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 800);
        setTimeout(function() { $('#mainForm').focus() }, 3000);
    }
});
```

None of them work. FYI, I changed the focus() to an addClass() function, and that works just fine. But focus is much preferred because it disappears when an individual input is selected. I'd rather not have to write another function to remove the class when an input is focused. Much thanks.

Comment: what is the target element for focus? could you post your html as well?

Comment: The target element is actually the `<form>` element itself. I want to highlight the entire element by focusing it when the link is clicked.

Comment: @Deep thanks for that question, it made me look into the `<form>` element and realize what the solution was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I actually figured this out myself. It had nothing to do with the jQuery code, but rather the HTML. In order for `.focus()` to have effect on an element like a `<form>`, it needs to have a `tabindex` value set to make it focusable. So I updated my html to look like this:

```
<form name="mainForm" id="mainForm" tabindex="-1">
```

Adding the `tabindex` value makes it work. And in case anyone cares, I used the following for my jQuery code, so that the page scroll happens before the focus. Otherwise the page will move to the bottom of the form when it's focused first, and then scroll up to beginning of the form:

```
$('a.slide-down').on('click', function(event) {
  var target = $(this).attr('href')
  if (target.length) {               
      event.preventDefault();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
      }, 800);
      $('#mainForm').focus();
    }
});
```

Thanks to everyone for the other suggestions though.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and sharing your solution. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `.focus()` is using to focus a form? 
In most of the case, focus will use at one input field for user input, you should select the input fields in that form but not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please refer this link, this is code which is used inside on click function

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).focus();
});
```

Visit https://api.jquery.com/focus/